# Error C2601: 'BlackOps2' : Local Function Definitions Are Illegal

Tags: c++, function, local

Please help, My error is "Error C2601: 'BlackOps2' : Local Function Definitions Are Illegal." I edited the post and added the full code. Please help. By the way, if anyone is confused, this is just the coding for ban bypasses. Here is my coding:

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
#include "Config.h"
#include "Utilities.h"
#include "TitleSpecificHooks.h"
#include "SystemHooks.h"
#include "PatchData.h"
#include "Utilities.h"
#include <xbdm.h>

extern HANDLE hXam;
extern DWORD ApplyPatches(CHAR* FilePath, const VOID* DefaultPatches = NULL);
extern int applyPatchData(DWORD* patchData);
wchar_t challengeNotify[XSTL_BUFFER_CHALLENGENOTIFYLEN];
SERVER_GET_CUSTOM_RESPONCE cData;

DWORD XSecurityCreateProcessHook(DWORD dwHardwareThread)
{
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

VOID XSecurityCloseProcessHook(){}

VOID __cdecl APCWorker(void* Arg1, void* Arg2, void* Arg3)
{

    // Call our completion routine if we have one
    if(Arg2)
        ((LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)Arg2)((DWORD)Arg3, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)Arg1);
}

DWORD XSecurityVerifyHook(DWORD dwMilliseconds, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
{

    // Queue our completion routine
    if(lpCompletionRoutine) 
        NtQueueApcThread((HANDLE)-2, (PIO_APC_ROUTINE)APCWorker, lpOverlapped, (PIO_STATUS_BLOCK)lpCompletionRoutine, 0);

    // All done
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

DWORD XSecurityGetFailureInfoHook(PXSECURITY_FAILURE_INFORMATION pFailureInformation)
{
    if (pFailureInformation->dwSize != 0x18) return ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
    pFailureInformation->dwBlocksChecked = 0;
    pFailureInformation->dwFailedReads = 0;
    pFailureInformation->dwFailedHashes = 0;
    pFailureInformation->dwTotalBlocks = 0;
    pFailureInformation->fComplete = TRUE;
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

DWORD XexGetProcedureAddressHook(HANDLE hand, DWORD dwOrdinal, PVOID* pvAddress)
{   
    // Check our module
    if(hand == hXam)
    {
        switch(dwOrdinal)
        {
            case 0x9BB:
                *pvAddress = XSecurityCreateProcessHook;
                return 0;
            case 0x9BC:
                *pvAddress = XSecurityCloseProcessHook;
                return 0;
            case 0x9BD:
                *pvAddress = XSecurityVerifyHook;
                return 0;
            case 0x9BE:
                *pvAddress = XSecurityGetFailureInfoHook;
                return 0;
        }
    }

    // Call our real function if we aren't interested
    return XexGetProcedureAddress(hand, dwOrdinal, pvAddress);
}
extern "C"
{
    NTSYSAPI
    EXPORTNUM(309)
    HRESULT
    NTAPI
    XNetLogonGetMachineID(
        IN OUT  QWORD* pqwMachineID
    );
}
NTSTATUS XeKeysGetKeyHook( WORD KeyId, PVOID KeyBuffer, PDWORD keyLength)
{
    if(KeyId == 0x14)
    {
        XUSER_SIGNIN_INFO userInfo;
        XamUserGetSigninInfo(0, XUSER_GET_SIGNIN_INFO_ONLINE_XUID_ONLY, &userInfo);

        BYTE gamertagSha[0x10];
        XeCryptSha((PBYTE)userInfo.szUserName, strlen(userInfo.szUserName), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, gamertagSha, 0x10);
        BYTE temp=0;

        for(int i=0; i<0xC; i++)
        {
            temp=(gamertagSha[i]&0xE)+'0';
            SetMemory(&((BYTE*)(KeyBuffer))[i], &temp, 1);
        }
    }
    else return XeKeysGetKey(KeyId, KeyBuffer, keyLength);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

HRESULT XeKeysGetConsoleIDHook( PBYTE databuffer OPTIONAL, char* szBuffer OPTIONAL ) 
{

    XE_CONSOLE_ID consoleID;
    XeKeysGetConsoleID((PBYTE)&consoleID, NULL);

    XUSER_SIGNIN_INFO userInfo;
    XamUserGetSigninInfo(0, XUSER_GET_SIGNIN_INFO_ONLINE_XUID_ONLY, &userInfo);

    BYTE gamertagSha[0x10];
    XeCryptSha((PBYTE)userInfo.szUserName, strlen(userInfo.szUserName), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, gamertagSha, 0x10);
    consoleID.MacIndex3 = gamertagSha[0];
    consoleID.MacIndex4 = gamertagSha[1];
    consoleID.MacIndex5 = gamertagSha[2];

    SetMemory(databuffer, &consoleID, 0x5);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

int NetDll_XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHook( XNCALLER_TYPE xnc, XNADDR * pxnaddr, ULONGLONG * pqwMachineId){

    int rett = NetDll_XNetXnAddrToMachineId( xnc, pxnaddr, pqwMachineId);

    XUSER_SIGNIN_INFO userInfo;
    XamUserGetSigninInfo(0, XUSER_GET_SIGNIN_INFO_ONLINE_XUID_ONLY, &userInfo);

    BYTE gamertagSha[0x10];
    XeCryptSha((PBYTE)userInfo.szUserName, strlen(userInfo.szUserName), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, gamertagSha, 0x10);
    SetMemory(pqwMachineId+5, gamertagSha, 0x3);

    return rett;
}
HRESULT XNetLogonGetMachineIDHook(QWORD* machineID)
{

    QWORD machID = 0;
    HRESULT rett = XNetLogonGetMachineID(&machID);

    XUSER_SIGNIN_INFO userInfo;
    XamUserGetSigninInfo(0, XUSER_GET_SIGNIN_INFO_ONLINE_XUID_ONLY, &userInfo);

    BYTE gamertagSha[0x10];
    XeCryptSha((PBYTE)userInfo.szUserName, strlen(userInfo.szUserName), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, gamertagSha, 0x10);
    SetMemory(machineID + 5, gamertagSha, 0x3);

    return rett;
}
typedef HRESULT (*pXamInputGetState)(QWORD r3,QWORD r4,QWORD r5);
pXamInputGetState XamInputGetState = (pXamInputGetState)ResolveFunction(NAME_XAM, 401);
static BOOL isFrozen = FALSE;
HRESULT XamInputGetStateHook(QWORD r3,QWORD r4,QWORD r5)
{
    if(isFrozen)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    HRESULT ret = XamInputGetState(r3, r4, r5);
}
BOOL isDevKit;
typedef enum _XBOX_GAMES : DWORD
{   
    COD_BLACK_OPS_2 = 0x415608C3,
    DASHBOARD = 0xFFFE07D1,
    FREESTYLEDASH = 0xF5D20000,
    COD_GHOSTS = 0x415608FC,
    COD_ADVANCED_WARFARE = 0x41560914
} XBOX_GAMES;

static DWORD lastTitleID = 0;
VOID InitializeTitleSpecificHooks(PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ModuleHandle)
{
        // Hook any calls to XexGetProcedureAddress
    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_KERNEL, 407, (DWORD)XexGetProcedureAddressHook);

    // If this module tries to load more modules, this will let us get those as well
    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_KERNEL, 408, (DWORD)XexLoadExecutableHook);
    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_KERNEL, 409, (DWORD)XexLoadImageHook);
    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_XAM, 401, (DWORD)XamInputGetStateHook);

    XEX_EXECUTION_ID* pExecutionId = (XEX_EXECUTION_ID*)RtlImageXexHeaderField(ModuleHandle->XexHeaderBase, 0x00040006);
    if (pExecutionId == 0) return;

    #ifdef SPOOF_MS_POINTS
        if (wcscmp(ModuleHandle->BaseDllName.Buffer, L"Guide.MP.Purchase.xex") == 0) 
        { 
            ApplyPatches(NULL, PATCH_DATA_MPPURCHASE_MSPOINTS_RETAIL);
        }
        else
        {
            //wprintf(L"\r\nChecked: %s\r\n", ModuleHandle->BaseDllName);
        }
    #endif

    VOID BlackOps2()
    {
    *(QWORD*)0x823C07C8 = 0x6000000038600000; //Demonware Be Gone
    BYTE Data[] = { 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x8259A65C, Data, 4); // Disable challenge log check
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497EB0, Data, 4); // Disable call to protections
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497F30, Data, 4); // Cheat
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497EE0, Data, 4); // Write
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497EC8, Data, 4); // Read
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599680, Data, 4); // Ban 1
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599670, Data, 4); // Ban 2
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599628, Data, 4); // Ban 3
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x8259964C, Data, 4); // Ban 4
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x825996AC, Data, 4); // Ban Checks
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x825996B4, Data, 4); // Console Checks
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599644, Data, 4); // XUID Check
    memcpy((BYTE*)0x8259964C, Data, 4); // Other
    Sleep(500);
    *(int*)0x821F5B7C = 0x38600001; //Redboxes
    *(int*)0x82259BC8 = 0x38600001; //No Recoil
    *(int*)0x821B8FD0 = 0x2B110001; //UAV
    *(int*)0x82255E1C = 0x2B110001; //Laser
    *(int*)0x821FC04C = 0x38C0FFFF; //Wallhack
}
VOID BlackOps2ZM()
{
    *(int*)0x8259A65C = 0x60000000; //TU18
    *(int*)0x825C6070 = 0x60000000; //TU18
    *(int*)0x824A7620 = 0x60000000; //TU18
}
DWORD WINAPI BO2Launch_Go(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    BlackOps2();
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI BO2ZMLaunch_Go(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    BlackOps2ZM();
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI GHOSTSLaunch_Go(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    *(DWORD*)0x82627614 = 0x39200009;
    *(DWORD*)0x82627628 = 0x38600000;
    *(DWORD*)0x82627634 = 0x39600001;
    *(DWORD*)0x82627650 = 0x38600002;
    *(DWORD*)0x8262767C = 0x48000010;
    *(DWORD*)0x826276D4 = 0x48000010;
    //*(QWORD*)(0x82627684) = 0x8921005061490000;
    //*(QWORD*)(0x826276DC) = 0x8921005061490000;
    Sleep(500);
    *(int*)0x82265384 = 0x39200001;
    *(int*)0x8226D2B4 = 0x60000000;
    *(int*)0x82266448 = 0x60000000;
    *(int*)0x8226C874 = 0x60000000;
    *(int*)0x8226BB74 = 0x60000000;
    *(int*)0x82290494 = 0x38C00005;
    *(int*)0x822C9344 = 0x60000000;
    return 0;
}

inline __declspec() bool Live_GetConsoleDetailsSavestub(unsigned char internalIP[4], unsigned char onlineIP[4], unsigned long long *machineIDH, unsigned long long *null, unsigned long long *enet)
{
    __asm
    {
        nop
            nop
            nop
            nop
            nop
            nop
            nop
            blr
    }
}

int XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHookBO2(XNCALLER_TYPE xnc, XNADDR *pxnaddr, unsigned long long MachineId)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    MachineId = 0xFA00000000000000 | (0x2000000 | rand() % 0x7FFFFF);
    return 0;
}

int XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHook(XNCALLER_TYPE xnc, XNADDR* pxnaddr, unsigned long long* qwMachineId)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    *qwMachineId = 0xFA00000002000000 | (0x2000000 | rand() % 0x7FFFFF);
    return 0;
}

bool Live_GetConsoleDetailsHookAW(unsigned char internalIP[4], unsigned char onlineIP[4], unsigned long long *machineIDH, unsigned long long *null, unsigned long long *enet)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int iTargetAddress = 0;
    __asm mflr      iTargetAddress
    if (iTargetAddress == 0x822C9FF8 || iTargetAddress == 0x822C9908)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            internalIP[i] = rand() % 0xFF; onlineIP[i] = rand() % 0xFF;
        }
        *enet = 0x001DD8000000 | rand() % 0x7FFFFF;
        return true;
    }
    return Live_GetConsoleDetailsSavestub(internalIP, onlineIP, machineIDH, null, enet);
}

unsigned long XeXGetModuleHandleHookk(char* ModuleName)
{
    if (strcmp(ModuleName, "xbdm.xex") == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (unsigned long)GetModuleHandle(ModuleName);
}
VOID InitializeTitleSpecificHooks(PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ModuleHandle)
{
    // Hook any calls to XexGetProcedureAddress
    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_KERNEL, 407, (DWORD)XexGetProcedureAddressHook);

    // If this module tries to load more modules, this will let us get those as well
    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_KERNEL, 408, (DWORD)XexLoadExecutableHook);

    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_KERNEL, 409, (DWORD)XexLoadImageHook);

    PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_XAM, 401, (DWORD)XamInputGetStateHook);

    // PatchModuleImport(ModuleHandle, NAME_XAM, 0x212, (DWORD)XamUserCheckPrivHook);

    XEX_EXECUTION_ID* pExecutionId = (XEX_EXECUTION_ID*)RtlImageXexHeaderField(ModuleHandle->XexHeaderBase, 0x00040006);
    if (pExecutionId == 0) return;

    if (pExecutionId->TitleID == BO2)
    {
        DWORD tu18v = 0x00001202;
        if (pExecutionId->Version < tu18v){
            return;
        }
        else if (pExecutionId->Version > tu18v){
            return returnToDash(L"Puregamer62's Bypass Failed: Wrong Title Update!");
        }
        else if (pExecutionId->Version == tu18v && lastTitleID != BO2){
            for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
                if (XamUserIsOnlineEnabled(i)){
                    return returnToDash(L"Puregamer62's Offline Files - Please Start Black Ops 2 Logged Out!");
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            isFrozen = TRUE;
            Sleep(10000);
            isFrozen = FALSE;
        }
        // HookFunctionStart((PDWORD)LiveStats_Probation_GiveProbation, (PDWORD)LiveStats_Probation_GiveProbationSaveStub, (DWORD)LiveStats_Probation_GiveProbationHook);
        if (wcscmp(ModuleHandle->BaseDllName.Buffer, L"default_mp.xex") == 0)
        {
            PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x8173DFA8, (DWORD)XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHookBO2, false);//Machine ID XAM 17349
            PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x82844820, (DWORD)XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHookBO2, false);//TU18 Machine ID From XeX

            BYTE Data[] = { 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x8259A65C, Data, 4); // Disable challenge log check
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497EB0, Data, 4); // Disable call to protections
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497F30, Data, 4); // Cheat
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497EE0, Data, 4); // Write
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82497EC8, Data, 4); // Read
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599680, Data, 4); // Ban 1
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599670, Data, 4); // Ban 2
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599628, Data, 4); // Ban 3
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x8259964C, Data, 4); // Ban 4
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x825996AC, Data, 4); // Ban Checks
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x825996B4, Data, 4); // Console Checks
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x82599644, Data, 4); // XUID Check
            memcpy((BYTE*)0x8259964C, Data, 4); // Other
            *(int*)0x824E0CD8 = 0x60000000; // XeXGetModuleHandle

            PatchInJump((PDWORD)(ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x212)), (DWORD)GoldSpoofHook, false);
            PatchInJump((PDWORD)(ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x195)), (DWORD)XeXGetModuleHandleHookk, false);
            PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x81A74DB4, (DWORD)XeKeysGetKeyHook, false); //XAM 17349
            Sleep(2000);
            XNotifyUI(L"Puregamer62's Offline Files - BO2 Multiplayer Bypass Activated!");
        }
            else if (wcscmp(ModuleHandle->BaseDllName.Buffer, L"default.xex") == 0)
            {
                PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x8173DFA8, (DWORD)XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHookBO2, false);//Machine ID XAM 17349
                PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x82844820, (DWORD)XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHookBO2, false);//TU18 Machine ID From XeX

                *(int*)0x824A7CB8 = 0x60000000; // Disable challenge log check
                *(int*)0x823CF858 = 0x60000000; // Disable call to protections
                *(int*)0x823CF8A0 = 0x60000000; // Cheat
                *(int*)0x823CF888 = 0x60000000; // Write
                *(int*)0x823CF870 = 0x60000000; // Read

                PatchInJump((PDWORD)(ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x195)), (DWORD)XeXGetModuleHandleHookk, false);
                PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x81A74DB4, (DWORD)XeKeysGetKeyHook, false); //XAM 17349
                Sleep(2000);
                XNotifyUI(L"Puregamer62's Offline Files - BO2 Zombies Bypass Activated!");

                Sleep(5000);
                    //Notify Client About Success!
                    XNotifyQueueUI(XNOTIFYUI_TYPE_PREFERRED_REVIEW, 0, 2, L"Sysclla - Black Ops 2 Bypass Enabled!", NULL);
    }
    else if (pExecutionId->TitleID == AW)
    {
        HookFunctionStart((PDWORD)0x8233B018, (PDWORD)Live_GetConsoleDetailsSavestub, (DWORD)Live_GetConsoleDetailsHookAW);
        PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x8173DFA8, (DWORD)XNetXnAddrToMachineIdHook, false);//Machine ID XAM 17349
        PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x8219EAA8, (DWORD)XNetXnAddrToMachineId, false);//Machine ID TU17
        {
            DbgPrint("Puregamer62's Offline Files - Hooked MachineID!");

            Sleep(1000);

            *(long long*)0x822CA190 = 0x8921005060000000;
            *(int*)0x822CA18C = 0x48000010;
            *(int*)0x822CA184 = 0x38600000;
            *(int*)0x822CA0EC = 0x3920331C;
            *(PBYTE)0x8233B0E7 = 0x00;


            PatchInJump((PDWORD)(ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x212)), (DWORD)GoldSpoofHook, false);
            PatchInJump((PDWORD)(ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x195)), (DWORD)XeXGetModuleHandleHookk, false);
            PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x81A74DB4, (DWORD)XeKeysGetKeyHook, false); //XAM
            Sleep(5000);
            XNotifyQueueUI(XNOTIFYUI_TYPE_PREFERRED_REVIEW, 0, 2, L"Puregamer62's Offline Files - Advanced Warfare Bypass Activated!", NULL);
        }

    }
    else if (pExecutionId->TitleID == GHOSTS)
    {
        if (wcscmp(ModuleHandle->BaseDllName.Buffer, L"default_mp.xex") == 0)
        {

                DbgPrint("Puregamer62's Offline Files - Hooked MachineID!");

                Sleep(1000);

                *(int*)0x826276D4 = 0x48000010;
                *(int*)0x826276CC = 0x38600000;
                *(int*)0x82627670 = 0x3920331C;

                PatchInJump((PDWORD)(ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x212)), (DWORD)GoldSpoofHook, false);
                PatchInJump((PDWORD)(ResolveFunction("xam.xex", 0x195)), (DWORD)XeXGetModuleHandleHookk, false);
                PatchInJump((PDWORD)0x81A74DB4, (DWORD)XeKeysGetKeyHook, false); //XAM
                Sleep(2000);
                XNotifyUI(L"Puregamer62's Offline Files - Ghosts Bypass Activated!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add full code to post

Answer (score 1):

You have `VOID BlackOps2() {` *inside* the function

```
VOID InitializeTitleSpecificHooks(PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ModuleHandle)
{
```

This is illegal in Standard C++. Some compilers allow this as an extension but it's not a good idea anyway.  You have several more functions afterwards which are also inside `InitializeTitleSpecificHooks`.

Another serious problem is that you have later on in the file:

```
VOID InitializeTitleSpecificHooks(PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ModuleHandle)
```

again. This is also wrong because you cannot have two different functions of the same name and signature.  Strangely, the two different functions have similar but not exactly the same code.

I'd guess that you have made an accidental copy-paste error somewhere or perhaps a version control merge has gone wrong, or something.  To fix this without a big headache you might be best off to roll back to a previous working version.